# Filtering and boosting on field based on time in SOLR

Tags: database, datetime, solr

I want to use filtering and boosting on documents based on a field value which is dependent on data collected on time ranges.

Ex.
I am dealing with multiple vendors to supply me goods.
Suppose there are 3 vendors and they have different time they can sell their goods. I want the vendor list based on certain product, I want to boost the vendor who can sell the product now.

I have information like this:

1. Vendor Does not sell on any sunday
2. It will definitely sell on monday from 2:00 to 4:00 PM

The rest of the time, I am not sure whether they are available to sell the product or not, so I will not boost their result.

How should I store this information and use the result in solr query?

Comment: Have you tried using a daterange field and boost against that to solve for #2, and use a regular filter query to remove entries that match the current day for #1?

Comment: how this is stored -- > "t will definitely sell on monday from 2:00 to 4:00 PM" ?

Comment: I used the approach suggested by @MatsLindh. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just map the availability (or in separate field non-availability) as an integer, probably at an hour resolution. So, if Monday is your week start, you can have 14,15,16 as availability for second condition. And then you just boost with [standard number or range search](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/the-standard-query-parser.html). (availability:15 or availability[14 TO 16].

For more complex searches, there is a trick to use geographical filtering for these kinds of things.

You basically map your availability (or in separate field non-availability) as a x,y coordinates in some space. Like a box in the calendar. So, your Sunday to Saturday is 0-6 on X and your hours are 0-24. Then, you condition 2 is 1,14-1,16 rectangle and you map the current time into that same concept and see if your dot is inside any of the rectangles in a boost query.

Basically, you decide on granularity and map your time into numbers or rectangles.